# Delete all input tags from an HTML form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, for-loop

I'm new to JavaScript and I've been trying for too long now.

I crafted this code, to **remove**, not clear or reset, all input tags from a form with a specific name. The input fields have different names, so I can't use the list of input fields with a specific name.

```
 <form action="/" method="get" name="aForm">
  A: <input type="text" name="a" value="a"><br>
  B: <input type="text" name="b" value="b"><br>
  C: <input type="text" name="c" value="c"><br>
  D: <input type="text" name="d" value="d"><br>
</form> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
  var aForm = document.forms["aForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
  var len = aForm.length;
  console.log("Form has "+len+" input fields.");

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
     aForm[i].remove();
     console.log("Removed number: "+i);
   }

  console.log("After the for loop: "+ aForm.length);
}
</script>
```

This removes the first and the third input field just fine, which is confuses me already. But then breaks as suddenlly `TypeError: aForm[i] is undefined`.

I do have experience in a number of different languages, but this just baffles me. I feel like I'm unable to use a for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a *live* list.

When you remove the element from the DOM, you also remove it from the list. This causes every other element to move down a position in the list.

To deal with this you can:

### Keep removing the first item until you've removed them all

```
while (aForm[0]) {
    aForm[0].remove();
}
```

### Loop over the list backwards

```
for (var i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    aForm[i].remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
function myFunction()
{
  var aForm = document.forms["aForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
  var len = aForm.length;
  console.log("Form has "+len+" input fields.");
  var i=0;
  while (aForm.length){
    aForm[0].remove();
    console.log("Removed number: "+i);
    i++;
  }

  console.log("After the for loop: "+ aForm.length);
}
```

```html
<form action="/" method="get" name="aForm">
  A: <input type="text" name="a" value="a"/><br>
  B: <input type="text" name="b" value="b"/><br>
  C: <input type="text" name="c" value="c"/><br>
  D: <input type="text" name="d" value="d"/><br>
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```